# A simple polynomial differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$ \frac{d}{dx}y(x) = -(y(x))^3. $$

with initial condition $y(0) = 1$.

I know that it admits the unique solution

$$ y(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{ 1 }{ 1 + 2 x } }. $$

How can I prove that this solution is unique?

Comment: Well the right hand side is local lipschitz hence  Picard-Lindelöf ...

Comment: Sure, but I would not like to invoke a given Theorem. I instead would like a proof relative to this particular example, for instance a constructive one by contradiction.

Comment: Picard Lindelöf has a constructive proof which gives you the solution via Banach's Fix Point Theorem.

Comment: Exactly. But I would not like to prove Banach's Fix Point Theorem to then prove Picard-Lindelöf Theorem to then prove that the given solution is unique. I would instead like a direct constructive proof by contradiction made just for this particular example. In other words, I do not want to prove that ANY Lipschitz RHS yields to a unique solution.

Comment: Maybe you extend your motivation for doing so. Just have the feeling it is homework and you didn't have this theorem so far, and I am not in the mood to do someones homework.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your comments. If you are not in the mood of solving this exercise, then please just forget this post. Nobody is forcing you!

Comment: So, is the variables separation trick enough? I mean $dy/y^3 = -dx$.

Comment: Yes, ir is. Since $y(0)=1$, you know that $y(x)\ne0$ on a neighborhood of $0$, and division by $y^3$ is fine.

Comment: Thanks Julian. Now, for other potential readers of this post, it would be convenient to write down a precise "Answer", which I can then mark as correct. Can you please do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to apply the separation of variables. For your Cauchy problem it writes

$$-\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{du}{u^3}=\int_0^t ds$$
or
$$ \frac{1}{2u^2}\Big|_{y(0)}^{y(t)}=t,$$
which gives

$$\frac{1}{(y(t))^2}=2t+1,$$
and finally $$y(t) = (2t+1)^{-1/2}.$$

All you need to do now is to prove that the method of separation of variables works.

Comment: Question is about uniqueness of the solution not how to solve it!

Comment: @user40615 The uniqueness is given by Picard-Lindelöf theorem; if you don't want to prove it, you might want to prove that the method of separation of variables works and produces the unique solution (and, as you see, this method applies to your case). In any case, you can read my another answer, I show uniqueness there by some trivial manipulations without using any theorems.

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved by the standard way. Let $y$ and $z$ be two solutions satisfying the given problem and set $w=y-z$. Then $w$ satisfies the equation $w'=-(y^3-z^3)=-w(y^2+yz+z^2)$ with zero initial condition. Multiply this equation by $w$ you will see that $ww'=-w^2(y^2+yz+z^2)$. Since the RHS of this equation is always non-positive ($y^2+yz+z^2\geq \frac{1}{2}(y^2+z^2)$) so we have $=(w^2/2)'= ww'\leq 0$. Integrating this inequality from $0$ to $x$ gives that $w^2(x)\leq 0$ and so you have $w=0$, or $y=z$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to prove that some bijective application of $y$ is unique.

In some neighbourhood of zero our function is positive, hence we can study the function $z(t) = y^{-2}(t)$. The application $y\to z$ is bijective,  hence we don't loose unicity.

Now we can write the differential equation on $z$:
$$z'= -2y^{-3}y' = 2,\quad z(0)=1.$$
Evidently, this equation has a unique solution $z=2t+1$. Note that, remarkably, we obtain that $y$ remains positive for all admissible $t$, hence our trick works everywhere.